# is it good practice to Any element type in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

is it good practice to Any element type in swift?

For example

```
let arrayObject = [Any]
```

or

```
let arrayObject  = [[String: String]]
```

Comment: Depend on your requirement or what you're going to store any dynamic data or standard data!

Comment: A good practice is to avoid `Any` as much as possible.

Comment: Ask yourself this. What would you gain from using `[Any]` ?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri the better question is: how much would you lose by using `[Any]`

Comment: @DávidPásztor If he is trying to use `Any` fruitfully he has to measure the gain not the loss. If there was a loss, he wouldn't even be considering the option. So, i believe i phrased it properly. (I understand you were taking a dig at the usage of `Any` but i don't think it fit the context here. :x)

Comment: @RakeshaShastri thanks for instant reply. I do believe "Any" is quit useful. It give me the flexibility to work around stuff.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the revert. I just wanted to know what other swift developers think in my context. basically what they think is Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Swift's strong type system encourages you to be **always as type specific as possible**. Please don't use `Any` as a *don't-care* type.

I'd recommend to consider this priority list (high to low)

1. If the type is known and homogenous, use the static type.
   For example in a JSON dictionary if all values are `String` use always `[String:String]` rather than `[String:Any]`.
2. If the type is heterogenous – for example objects in an array – and contains only a few known types use a common protocol.
3. Try to use generics.
4. Use `Any`

Answer (score 0):

When you know your Array element's type you can avoid using `Any` and use the direct data type.

For example: If you are holding array of `String`, you can directly define `String` type as like below.

```
var arrayObject = [String]()
```

If you are holding an unknown type of objects in array or multiple types of objects in array, you can go with `Any`.

For example: If you are holding `String` and `NSNumber` in same array, you can define `Any` as type of array element as like below.

```
var arrayObject = [Any]()
arrayObject.append("Hundred")
arrayObject.append(NSNumber(value: 100))

let str = arrayObject[0] as! String
let number = arrayObject[1] as! NSNumber
```

Comment: You *can* but you should *not*. `Any` is the worst choice. For example you could declare the array containing `String` and `NSNumber` as `[CustomStringConvertible]` which is a hundred times better than `[Any]`.

Comment: If we should not use `Any` and is worst choice, why `Swift` has such type?.  I just gave a basic example and another example is `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCell", owner: nil, options: nil)`, here `loadNibNamed` function returns the array of `Any`. So it's meaningful at this point. Right?